# ERROR: Could not build wheels for netifaces, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-wheel, libgcc, python-netifaces, balena

I am trying to deploy some code onto a remote Raspberry Pi CM4 hub running BalenaOS. However, my build has been failing while trying to install the `netifaces` library. The error message is as follows:

```
Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py): started
[main]       Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[main]       error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[main]       × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
[main]       │ exit code: 1
[main]       ╰─> [37 lines of output]
[main]           /home/gateway-hub/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
[main]           !!
[main]                   ********************************************************************************
[main]                   The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
[main]                   By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
[main]                   or your builds will no longer be supported.
[main]                   See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
[main]                   ********************************************************************************
[main]           !!
[main]             parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
[main]           running bdist_wheel
[main]           running build
[main]           running build_ext
[main]           checking for getifaddrs...not found.
[main]           checking for getnameinfo...not found.
[main]           checking for socket IOCTLs...not found.
[main]           checking for optional header files...none found.
[main]           checking whether struct sockaddr has a length field...no.
[main]           checking which sockaddr_xxx structs are defined...none!
[main]           checking for routing socket support...no.
[main]           checking for sysctl(CTL_NET...) support...no.
checking for netlink support...no.
building 'netifaces' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.11.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c netifaces.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/netifaces.o
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/include/syslimits.h:7,
[main]                            from /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/include/limits.h:34,
[main]                            from /usr/local/include/python3.9/Python.h:11,
[main]                            from netifaces.c:1:
[main]           /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/include/limits.h:203:15: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
[main]             203 | #include_next <limits.h>                /* recurse down to the real one */
[main]                 |               ^~~~~~~~~~
[main]           compilation terminated.
[main]           error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
[main]           [end of output]
[main]       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[main]     
[main]       ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
[main]     
[main]       Running setup.py clean for netifaces
[main]     Successfully built pykafka
[main]     Failed to build netifaces
[main]     ERROR: Could not build wheels for netifaces, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am attempting to deploy this code using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && apt-get install --reinstall libgcc-12-dev

RUN groupadd gateway-hub &&\
    useradd gateway-hub -m -g gateway-hub
USER gateway-hub

WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=gateway-hub:gateway-hub . .
RUN cd /app
CMD ["python3", "-m", "venv", "."]
RUN chmod +x /app/environ.sh
RUN /app/environ.sh
```

environ.sh (set up virtual environment, install requirements):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if virtual environment exists
if [ ! -d "/home/gateway-hub/hub/bin" ]; then
    # Create the virtual environment
    python -m venv "/home/gateway-hub/hub"
fi

# Activate the Python virtual environment
source "/home/gateway-hub/hub/bin/activate"

# Update python dependencies if needed
if [ requirements_changed ]; then
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
    pip install -r "/app/requirements.txt"
fi
```

I've attempted to fix this with the following:

- reinstalling `libgcc-12-dev`
- update `pip`, `setuptools`
- install `netifaces` separately with the `--use-pep517` flag as explained here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
- install `netifaces` separately with the `--no-binary :all:` and/or `--no-cache-dir` flags
- install the `wheel` library separately

All of the following resulted in the same error message shown above.

Is this an issue where some other package is missing or needs updated, or could this potentially be an issue with my hardware?

Comment: How about installing the `linux-libc-dev` package in your `apt-get install` lines?

Comment: @bbayles added `apt-get install -y linux-libc-dev` to the install lines and got the same error again, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `python3-dev` package is missed with `python:3.9-slim` image. Try to install it during the first `RUN`

Comment: using `python:3.9` instead of `python:3.9-slim` did solve this problem for me